# DirectShow WAV file source does not produce any sound when graph runs

Tags: windows, winapi, audio, wav, directshow

We have a DirectShow application where we capture video input from USB, multiplex with audio from a WAV file (backing music), overlay audio and video effects, compress and write to an MP4 file.

Originally we were using an audio input source (microphone) and mixing our backing music and sound effects over the top but the decision was made to not capture live audio, and so I thought it would make more sense to use the backing music WAV file itself as the audio source.

Here is the filter graph we have:

[image]

`backing.wav` is a simple WAV file (stored locally), and was added to the graph using `IFilterGraph::AddSourceFilter`.

The problem is that when the graph is run, no audio samples are delivered from the WAV file. The video part of the graph runs as normal, but it's as if the audio part of the graph simply isn't running.

If I stop the graph in GraphEdit, add the `Default DirectSound Device` audio renderer and hook that up in place of the AAC Encoder filter and then run the graph again, the audio plays as you would expect.

Additionally, if `backing.wav` is replaced with an audio capture source like a microphone, audio data flows through as normal.

Does anyone have any ideas why the above graph, using a WAV file as the audio source, would fail to produce any audio samples?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the title is incorrectly identifying/summarizing the problem. There is nothing to tell for the fact that audio is not produced. It is likely that it is produced equally well with DirectSound Renderer and with AAC Encoder, specifically the data is reaching output pin of Mixing Transform Filter (is this your filter? You should be able to trace its flow and see media samples passing though).

With the information given, I would say it's likely that custom AAC encoder somehow does not like the feed and somehow either drops data or switches to erroneous state. You should be able to debug this further by inserting a Sample Grabber (or alike) filter¹ before the AAC encoder and tracing the media samples. Also comparing them to data from another source. The encoder might be sensitive to small details like media sample duration or discontinuity flag on the first sample streamed.

¹ With [GraphStudioNext](https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next) (GraphEdit makes no longer sense compared to) you can use internal Analyzer Filter and review media sample flow interactively using filter property page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no - the title is correct. The Mixing Transform Filter is our own filter, and I can set a breakpoint on its `CTransInPlaceFilter::Transform` function and the breakpoint is never hit. If I add the DirectSound Renderer in GraphEdit and hook it up, suddenly our breakpoint is hit.

Comment: You are interested in adding Sample Grabber/Analyzer before your filter first. It's highly unlikely that there is no input on your mixing filter (even in that case it's not source who is not producing audio, but rather wave parser). Your Transform method might be late breakpoint, the filter might fail inside between IPin::Receive entry point and Transform method.

Comment: If you still prefer breakpoints in your code, then `CTransformInputPin::Receive` is a better position.

Comment: Also note that your hooking DS renderer is not a clean test. Your filter derives from `CTransInPlaceFilter` which means that it's setting it up to possible negotiate shared memory allocator on both pins. With another output pin connection it might set it up to use a different code path. That is whatever the problem is the first thing to look is your filter, not the source which is plain and straightforward in generating audio feed. I am pretty sure it works equally well in all your runs...

Comment: Some further info: `CTransformInputPin::Receive` actually does get called a few times when the graph is run. Then `CTransformInputPin::EndOfStream` is called (from `quartz.dll!CBaseOutputPin::DeliverEndOfStream`), and following that `CTransformInputPin::Receive` is never called again. It's almost as if the sound file is running from the end rather than the beginning. I've tried GraphStudioNext but it fails to insert its Analyzer Filter (`VFW_E_CANNOT_CONNECT`). Do you have any idea why the audio stream would be ending seemingly before it even begins?

Comment: EOS is a result of certain error. Perhaps you should see non `S_OK` code returned by `Receive` call. Or, another reason is that downstream filters update memory allocator and shrink buffers so that Wave Parser is unable to deliver large chunk of data. Your seeing Receive call means that source and parser are actually starting a good session (and they are fine).

Comment: `Receive` isn't returning any errors from what I can tell. Any idea where I should look? Or any idea why the Analyzer Filter in GSN won't connect to anything?

Comment: Just to make sure, it's not about returning errors only, S_FALSE would/could also cause end of transmission. I tried to connect analyzer to wave parser and it connected for me. Where it fails for you? Its connection to wave parser or to your filter?

Comment: If I build the graph manually in GSN I can connect it ok, but when connecting to the remote graph in our app (graph is stopped), connection to wave parser output pin fails with `VFW_E_CANNOT_CONNECT`.

Comment: It's okay then, GSN is unable to inject its internal filter into your process.

Comment: The EOS is coming from `CBaseMSRWorker::DoEndOfData` which makes me think something has caused the WAV file to seek to the end, but I really have no idea where to look. So GSN can't be used to analyze remote graphs?

Comment: I'd check why you get Receive but not Transform. Apparently you did not expect that any media sample is lost/dropped without reaching Transform method. I suppose you can step the code through to identify this cause.

Comment: `Receive` is called exactly 385 times every time it seems, so I set a hit count breakpoint and traced through the last time. There are no errors anywhere that I can see. The sample is fed through to `CTransInPlaceFilter::Receive`, it gets given to `CTransformOutputPin::Deliver` which returns `S_OK` as normal. It's just that `Receive` is never called again. I wonder if there's just a fundamental problem combining a video input that never ends (camera) with one with a finite length (audio file). Perhaps it's simply not possible.